# Does iTunes Match keep updating?

Tags: icloud, itunes-match

I just subscribed to iTunes Match and it's currently scanning my library.

I've got a few tracks named as 'track 1', 'track 2', and 'unknown artist'. My plan is to clean up my library (some day). But will iTunes Match be able to rescan the new names of already matched songs?

In other words, will iTunes Match re-sync those songs already synced or will it only sync newly added songs?

Comment: I decided not to turn it on before I clean up my "various artist" and "track 1"s :)

Comment: That's a wise decision :) I wish I had the same attitude, but I could wait :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. The iTunes Match Library icon shows up from time to time (I haven't figured out what the exact requirements are) and you can re-scan your library.

Once you changed your id3 data, select the songs, right-click and select "Add to iCloud". This initiates a re-scan in iTunes Match as well.

If you add music, it will by added to iCloud instantly.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent all day redoing all my album artwork and then I realised that it looks good on my Mac, but iTunes Match just doesn't "match". So after a lot of looking around, this is the best way to do it:

1. Turn iTunes Match on.
2. <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> (highlight all Albums) and <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace ⌫</kbd> (delete).
3. When asked "this will delete all blah blah blah..... check box "delete from iCloud".
4. NOW BE CAREFUL... select "keep files" THIS IS *VERY* IMPORTANT!!!
5. it takes a while, then it all goes blank....and then more "iCloud" songs appear, Delete them too, same as step 3.
6. now you have an empty iTunes and an empty iCloud/iTunes Match!
   6a. Turn off iTunes Match!
7. go to import files, and select the iTunes folder, locate Music and select it.
8. and all your songs will return, some will have missing artwork, but they are the legit iTunes ones so just select "get album artwork".
9. the few that are not there just add them manually (i had 10 out of 4886 (not bad)
10. then go to "Store" and turn iMatch back on and it will rescan and re-upload as new.

This was the simplest way I found to do it.

Comment: Just a reminder, it takes time for iCloud to get up to speed, it's been 2 hrs and 90% of my albums are now correct on my iPad/iPhone give it time.....it is working on it .

Comment: As this is kind of a risky approach, you may want to make a) to make sure that your whole iCloud content is downloaded and b) that you have a backup of ~/Music/iTunes